# Relentless Super marathon?

Tags: biology, hard-science, biochemistry

Humans are not the fastest mammals on the planet, but for very long distances (more than 40 kilometers) we can overtake any species living on land. Except some dogs.

The best runners on ultra-long distances it is a mark of husky and small-scale, which was brought out for races on sled.
Carrying cargo they do not stop passing 5 marathons a day for a week or more (9 days = 1600 kilometers)

All thanks to an unusual way of turning food into energy.

The next is a small lecture on this: "in all mammals two types of fuels are used: glycogen (into which carbohydrates generate quite a lot of energy (at a short-term moment) into a brief last leap when energy is especially needed), fats and proteins burn not so well and are a long-term reserve of energy.

Glycogen supplies runners for brief especially fast distances, but tk it quickly ends runners for longer distances mostly rely on protein and fat. Only to burn fat and protein most mammals need to constantly burn a lot of glycogen, which is a problem, constantly the body can store very little glycogen and at the same time it is difficult to produce. By this runners run and get tired much faster than they could.

But driving dogs never fall without strength, because at the beginning of the arrival their body somehow turns into a state of burning fats without glycogen. Fats and proteins turn into energy almost instantly so dogs can resupply along the way.
We don 't quite understand how it works, but after nine days and two thousand kilometers passed, most dogs come to the finish line with the same indicators.

Moreover, unlike people ultra departures after marathons who have to lay down for months, driving dogs (husky malamut) do not give almost any sign of fatigue.
( https://youtu.be/HDG4GSypcIE )

My question: How does this biochemical mechanism actually work to turn food into energy and can such a mechanism be created in my genetically modified people, so that they are not so tired when running and other physical activity?

Comment: I have the impression this is better suited to biology  than to worldbuilding. You are asking the details of a biochemical mechanism of a real species.

Comment: You'd definitley need to cite the sources for your claims in any case to make it a hard-science question.

Comment: Genetically modified humans and hard science tend not to go well together. Legalities tend to restrict research in the areas of messing with human genetics.

Comment: My suspicion is that this would have downsides for thought. Huskies in my limited exposure tend to become very focused on running during this sort of exertion. Someone with more bio knowledge: would the alternate energy pathway be able to supply the extremely energy-intense human brain?

Comment: I don't have the details at hand. But it's all about aerobic vs anaerobic metabolism and burning carbs vs fats. You could look for books and lectures by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covert_Bailey for details. His lectures are what I learned about this.

Comment: Heat man, remember those dogs only outran a human IF its cold. Otherwise, we have superior cooling.

Comment: By what changes in the structure of the human body can you get rid of the above problem of overheating?

Comment: AFAIK researchers aiming at the big profits of slimming products are playing with hormones to push fat burning. For the moment it seems quite risky, but could it solve your problem without involving genetics?

Comment: Agree with BLT-Bub, please cite the source of your assertions.  I completed a 100 km ultramarathon 3 days ago and I am definitely not needing to "lay down for months".

Comment: I think Kangaroos can go further in a marathon because they are the most energy-efficient mammals when it comes to going long distances.

Answer (score 2):

From a world-building perspective, biology is mushier than physics. Every kind of energetic system has benefits and penalties. Great apes are vastly stronger than humans in short bursts because of how their muscles contract, but they would be relatively useless as laborers because we are built to maintain a modest energy output over a long period. You wouldn't need to explain the mechanism as long as there was a reasonable metabolic trade-off like long sleep periods or uncontrolled appetite. Mush dogs eat a constant high-calorie diet. I know at least one account of a long distance runner who became a runner after having suffered a traumatic brain injury and having short-term memory loss. Fatigue is relative, and they kept running because they didn't perceive a big difference. People might perform extreme endurance acts just by an appropriate mind trick.

Answer (score 0):

**They are better at breathing**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VO2_maxhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VO2_max

The reaction to convert any form of fat/sugar into energy requires oxygen; one of the major constraints in endurance exercise is getting enough oxygen into the body over a sustained period. An animal with a better oxygen intake and better circulation would likely be able to run at higher energy output for a longer time (or conversely seem less tired after the same amount of endurance).

In the real world this is what blood doping in cycling aimed to achieve (with some great success!) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_doping. It wouldn't be too much of a stretch to fictionally genetically modify humans to achieve similar effects.